# Firebase custom oauth how to setup provider name?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup Firebase custom OAuth using Java as JWT server. I am able to successfully setup this.

But when I am trying to login using the custom token the provider field in the Auth page leaves empty any help how to setup to my own text?

Comment: By "the provider field in the Auth page leaves empty", did you mean the provider displayed in the Firebase Console | Auth tab?

Comment: yes, how do I fill that field with my own text ? is possible?

Comment: Not supported for now. The Auth tab displays some fixed string like 'Custom login' if users login with custom token.

Comment: Thanks But this may be a nice to have feature